# How to useResultCache with fetch EAGER

Tags: php, caching, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have specified `fetch="EAGER"` to a relation of an entity, in this way:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(
 *  targetEntity="Toms\Entity\Channel",
 *  mappedBy="parent",
 *  cascade={"persist"},
 *  fetch="EAGER"
 * )
 * @var ArrayCollection
 */
protected $children;
```

It creates a new query each time `$channel->children` is called, but each query is not cached.

If I don't specify `fetch="EAGER"`, the cache works fine.
How can I cache also those queries?